# Node.JS минификаторы

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, минификация

Рендерю все страницы для юзеров на сервере, так вот мне нужно минифицировать все html, css, и js.

Но есть проблема, некоторые html содержат в себе так-же css и js. То-есть тот-же js для компонента может не идти отдельным файлом, а лежать в теле html.

Я пробовал [html-minifer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), однако он минифицирует всё, кроме js. Притом даже, если я в настройках укажу `{ minifyJS: true }`[image: 1]

Вот пример того, как я использовал minify:

```
const minify   = require('html-minifier').minify;
const template = `
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Some Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <style>
        body {
          background: black;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
        onload = () => {
          alert('Hello World!')
        }
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
`;

const response = minify(template, {
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  conservativeCollapse: false,
  decodeEntities: true,
  keepClosingSlash: false,
  preserveLineBreaks: false,
  preventAttributesEscapin: true,
  processConditionalComments: true,
  removeAttributeQuotes: true,
  removeComments: true,
  trimCustomFragments: true,
  useShortDoctype: true,
  minifyCSS: true,
  minifyJS: true
});

console.log(response);
```

И вот что я получил в консоли:[image: 3]

Так-же я пробовал [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)! Но получил следующие сообщение ошибки:

> unexpected token: operator (<)

Насколько я понимаю - этот конфликт возникает на почве того, что я пытаюсь минифицировать js внутри html, а не отдельно лежащий js.

Так вот вопрос:

- Какой модуль поможет мне минифицировать весь html включая css и js?

При этом многие css, js не находятся в теле html, а некоторые присутствуют и это всё нужно как можно сильнее минифицировать.

Comment: **Статус: не воспроизводится**. Я использую [**grunt-contrib-htmlmin**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin) (wrapper для HTML-minifier) в моих проектах → [**опция `minifyJS`**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/44795cd28bdd87703a2a865a709afa2ca670d11d/grunt/htmlmin.coffee#L48) минифицирует встроенный в HTML JavaScript. // `Желательные действия`: Пожалуйста, выложите [**MCVE**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) в виде кода, а не картинки, и покажите, как Вы запускаете HTML-minifier. Спасибо.

Comment: `Примечание`: Удостоверьтесь, что Вам действительно необходимо встраивать JavaScript в HTML, а не [**использовать атрибуты `async` и `defer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/5951529). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных. Я отредактировал вопрос, и добавил пример кода, который я использовал.

Comment: @СашаЧерных 

>Удостоверьтесь, что Вам действительно необходимо встраивать JavaScript в HTML. На моём сайте используются компоненты. Каждый компонент - это отдельный файл, который мы можем отобразить на одной странице и не отображать на другой. Для удобства я сделал html css и js этого компонента в одном файле, а не 150 дополнительных отдельных файлов.

Comment: KiiDii, `onload = () =>` — конструкция из EcmaScript 6, что [**не поддерживается**](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/659) в UglifyJS. Когда ES6 не используется, JavaScript в моих примерах минифицируется. Попробуйте [**использовать terser вместо UglifyJS**](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues/967#issuecomment-444675893) (и там всё обсуждение issue как раз по Вашей проблеме). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных я попробовал использовать terser, но та-же ошибка, что и с uglifyJS - "unexpected token: operator (<)"; Это явно из-за того, что js находится в теле html, ибо удалив весь html и оставив один js - мы получим минифицированный код. Или есть возможность использовать terser в самом html-minifier?

Comment: KiiDii , [**по ссылке из реплики выше**](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues/967#issuecomment-444675893) пользователь danielvaijk показывает, как он использует terser в самом html-minifier. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ах да! Простите, я не заметил коллбека) Спасибо большое) Кстати какие настройки для минифера больше всего минифицируют весь код? Тот, который указал автор являются хорошим примером?

Comment: KiiDii, я использую [**такую**](https://github.com/Kristinita/KristinitaPelican/blob/44795cd28bdd87703a2a865a709afa2ca670d11d/grunt/htmlmin.coffee) конфигурацию; в коде много комментариев, что и зачем. `какие настройки для минифера больше всего минифицируют весь код` — в моём примере настройки максимально минифицируют код, при этом сохраняя его валидным для Nu HTML Checker, HTML Tidy, htmllint и HTMLHint. Спасибо.